# Multiplication Rule, number of choices doesn’t depend on our prior selections

Tags: combinatorics

Let’s suppose that there are 15 students in a class, and that they’ve decided to choose a set of class ofﬁcers: a president, a vice president, a secretary and a treasurer. How many possible slates are there? That is, how many ways are there of choosing the four ofﬁcers?

Suppose that we impose the rule that no person can hold more than one ofﬁce. How many ways are there of choosing ofﬁcers now?

15 × 14 × 13 × 12 = 32,760

Note one point here: in this example, the actual choice of, say, the vice-president does depend on who we chose for president; the choice of a secretary does depend on who we selected for president and vice president, and so on. **But the number of choices doesn’t depend on our prior selections, so the multiplication principle still applies.**

My questions regards this last statement "*The number of choices doesn't depend on our prior selections, so the multiplication principle still applies*", how is it possible that the number of choices doesn't depend on our prior selections.

If we make the first selection(the president), the second choice (vice president) depends on the previous one, given that the number of choices shrinked to 14.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What they are saying is that whether you chose A or B, say, for president, the *number* of choices for vice-president will be $14$ and so on.

Comment: Let's talk about five people for now... they are $a,b,c,d,e$.  Originally the set of all people is $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and has five people in it.  Now... suppose we were to remove one person... $\{a,b,c,d,e\}\setminus \{x\}$ where $x\in \{a,b,c,d,e\}$.  We would have $5 - 1 = 4$ people afterwards...  Now, this is true regardless which person $x$ was and we were left with the remaining people as $\{b,c,d,e\}$ or $\{a,c,d,e\}$ or $\{a,b,d,e\}$ etc... all options of what we are left with will have $4$ people.  That's all the statement is saying.

Comment: In fancier mathy words... so long as $Y\subseteq X$ you have that $|X\setminus Y| = |X|-|Y|$ and this is true regardless what the contents of $X$ and $Y$ are specifically.